# How to get the CCBAnimationManager from a custom class in cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm loading a CCB file from my Cocos2d-x project, but I can't get access to the CCBAnimationManager from a custom class.

In Cocos2d with objective-C is as simple as:

CCBAnimationManager* animationManager = self.userObject;

But the same implementation in C++ returns a null value and the execution will cause a crash...

any idea? Thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is not quite simple as in obj-C. New TestCpp project got an example for this. Look at the (CocosBuilderTest->AnimationsTest).

Basically you need to create a CCNodeLoaderLibrary and register it with your custom loader class.

```
CCNodeLoaderLibrary * ccNodeLoaderLibrary = CCNodeLoaderLibrary::newDefaultCCNodeLoaderLibrary();

ccNodeLoaderLibrary->registerCCNodeLoader("TestAnimationsLayer", AnimationsTestLayerLoader::loader());
```

and then Create a CCBReader with that ccNodeLoaderLibrary

```
cocos2d::extension::CCBReader * ccbReader = new cocos2d::extension::CCBReader(ccNodeLoaderLibrary);
```

and now, you will be able to get hold of CCBAnimationManager via this ccbReader

```
ccbReader->getAnimationManager()
```

Comment: Yes, the current version of cocos2dx implements this... in the previous it was not working, thanks.